# Socket io (server) on client started listening event

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

https://github.com/marataziat/drawify In my GitHub project the socket io server is not waiting for a client configured event listener. My app server sends users count to counter on every user's connect/disconnect:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ..
   socket.broadcast.emit('users', { count: clientCount })
    ..
   socket.on('disconnect', function (msg) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('users', { count: clientCount });
   })
```

How to do for server wait for client configure his event listener?

Comment: You need to be more specific for your problem. What is an expected behavior? What is a current problem?

Comment: How to do for server wait for client configure his event listener?

Comment: Server doesn't know the client's behavior, and server doesn't have to wait for it. Client requests to the server when it's ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client you can detect if the connection is completed ([refer](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#event-connect)) and then fire an event to notify the server about this.

Example: Client side:

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('client-connected');
});
```

Server side:

```
socket.on('client-connected', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('users', { count: clientCount });
})
```

Comment: Maybe better to make expressjs API endpoint for initial getting the users count?